# How to show single list item on all screen at a time?

Tags: android, listview

I have list on android. Each time user slide screen left or right I need to show them single item with details. Which method should I use for this situation.

Example screenshots:
First Item

[first item http://imageshack.us/a/img707/9789/slide1t.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img707/9789/slide1t.png)

Second Item appears when user slide to left

[first item http://imageshack.us/a/img163/7351/slide2nl.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img163/7351/slide2nl.png)

Comment: To do this, you should seperate header and detail view.

Comment: @talhakosen both header and detail will change. It is not important point. Important one is, changing screen when user slide it. Same activity but next list element will show to user.

Comment: i see you can use viewpager to do this, i post my answer pls look the tutorial in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found simple solution for my question. ViewSwitcher with OnGestureListener solves my problem.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGwG8-chUEM

References:

ViewFlipper: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html

ViewSwitcher: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html

GestureDetector.OnGestureListener: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html

Source Code: 
http://www.mediafire.com/?fg32sn1345xn5dl

My activity doesn't have all code, so maybe it may not work. But logic is here.

-------My solution--------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ViewSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/viewSwitcher"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#65ffffff" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtHeader"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDetail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtKurum"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="0" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ViewSwitcher>

</LinearLayout>
```

-Activity-

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnGestureListener {

    ArrayList<String> liste;

    TextView txtHeader;
    TextView txtDetail;

    private ViewSwitcher switcher;

    int bakiyeCounter = 0;
    private GestureDetector gesturedetector = null;

    int SWIPE_MIN_VELOCITY = 100;
    int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 100;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bakiye);
        switcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher);
        txtHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
        txtDetail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDetail);
        gesturedetector = new GestureDetector(this, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        // Get Position
        float ev1X = e1.getX();
        float ev2X = e2.getX();

        // Get distance of X (e1) to X (e2)
        final float xdistance = Math.abs(ev1X - ev2X);

        final float xvelocity = Math.abs(velocityX);

        if ((xvelocity > SWIPE_MIN_VELOCITY)
                && (xdistance > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE)) {
            if (ev1X > ev2X)// Switch Left
            {
                if (bakiyeCounter < liste.size() - 1) {
                    bakiyeCounter++;
                    previousView();
                }
            } else// Switch Right
            {
                if (bakiyeCounter > 0) {
                    bakiyeCounter--;
                    nextView();
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void previousView() {


        txtHeader.setText(liste.get(bakiyeCounter).getHeader());
        txtDetail.setText(liste.get(bakiyeCounter).getDetail());
        switcher.showPrevious();

    }

    private void nextView() {

        txtDetail.setText(liste.get(bakiyeCounter).getHeader());
        txtHeader.setText(liste.get(bakiyeCounter).getDetail());
        switcher.showNext();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return gesturedetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
            float distanceY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use ViewPageIndicator https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Answer (score 1):

A combination of ViewPageIndicator as mentioned by TOMKA and the ExpandableListView should do the trick: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Answer (score 1):

Yo can look at below tutorial,

[http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/view-pager-example-in-android-
development/](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/view-pager-example-in-android-development/)

[image]